# How do you set the duration for UICollectionView Animations?

Tags: ios, ios6, grid, collectionview

I have a custom flow layout which is adjusting the attributes for cells when they are being inserted and deleted from the CollectionView with the following two functions, but I'm unable to figure out how you would adjust the default animation duration.

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

    // Assign the new layout attributes
    attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    attributes.alpha = 0;

    return attributes;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

    // Assign the new layout attributes
    attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    attributes.alpha = 0;

    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: According the Apple's documentation, "When animating layout changes, the animation timing and parameters are controlled by the collection view." This is in reference to the setCollectionView:animated: method, but I suspect that the same is true for modifying the bounds of the collection view. Sorry I can't be more help, I'm stuck on the same problem. I suspect that the answer lies somewhere within the UICollectionView object itself.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To solve problem without hack that was proposed in the [answer by gavrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15146098/1987748)
you could subclass UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes with new property `CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation`, than create custom transformation with a suitable duration  and assign it to attributes in `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath`, then in UICollectionViewCell apply the attributes as needed:

```
@interface AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
@property (nonatomic, strong)  CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation;
@end

@implementation AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super copyWithZone:zone];
    attributes.transformAnimation = _transformAnimation;
    return attributes;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {
    if (other == self) {
        return YES;
    }
    if (!other || ![[other class] isEqual:[self class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    if ([(( AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *) other) transformAnimation] != [self transformAnimation]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
@end
```

In Layout class

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath {
    AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = (AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes* )[super initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

    CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    transformAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
    CGFloat height = [self collectionViewContentSize].height;

    transformAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 2*height, height)];
    transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, attributes.bounds.origin.y, 0)];
    transformAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    attributes.transformAnimation = transformAnimation;
    return attributes;
}

+ (Class)layoutAttributesClass { 
    return [AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes class]; 
}
```

then in UICollectionViewCell apply the attributes

```
- (void) applyLayoutAttributes:(AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
{
    [[self layer] addAnimation:layoutAttributes.transformAnimation forKey:@"transform"];
}
```

Comment: You also need to override `+layoutAttributesClass` to return `[AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes class]` in the layout class.

Comment: `+ (Class)layoutAttributesClass
{
   return [AnimationCollectionViewLayoutAttributes class];
}`

Comment: add above method in your CustomFlowLayout.m class!

Answer (score 12):

Building on  @rotava's answer, you can temporarily set the animation speed by using a batch update of the collection view:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView.viewForBaselineLayout.layer setSpeed:0.2];
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths: insertedIndexPaths];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.collectionView.viewForBaselineLayout.layer setSpeed:1];
}];
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the boolean `finished` is important here. At some calls (I don't remember exactly which ones right now), the `completion` block is called more than once. To be completely sure that the animations have finished, I would do `if ( finished ) { /* ... */ }`. Why isn't that necessary here? Or is it and you just skipped it?

Comment: If `performBatchUpdates` has a chance of being called while previous animations are in progress, setting layer's speed back to 1 will cause previous animations to "jump forward" (as time scaling changes), even to final positions. Provided you do not need any other animations (except for those from `performBatchUpdates `) you can set the layer's speed and leave it that way.

Answer (score 5):

After trying `[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:]` and `[UIView setAnimationDuration:]` in every possible phase of the layout process without success, I figured out a somewhat hacky way to change the duration of cell animations created by `UICollectionView` that doesn't rely on private API's.

You can use `CALayer`'s `speed` property to change the relative media timing of animations performed on a given layer. For this to work with `UICollectionView`, you can change `layer.speed` to something less than 1 on the cell's layer. Obviously it's not great to have the cell's layer ALWAYS have a non-unity animation speed, so one option is to dispatch an `NSNotification` when preparing for cell animations, to which your cells subscribe, that will change the layer speed, and then change it back at an appropriate time after the animations are finished.

I don't recommend using this approach as a long-term solution as it's pretty roundabout, but it does work. Hopefully Apple will expose more options for UICollectionView animations in the future.

Answer (score 4):

`UICollectionView` initiates all animations internally using some hardcoded value. However, you can always override that value until animations are committed. 
In general, process looks like this:

- begin animations
- fetch all layout attribues
- apply attributes to views (UICollectionViewCell's)
- commit animations

applying attributes is done under each UICollectionViewCell and you can override animationDuration in appropriate method. The problem is that UICollectionViewCell has public method `applyLayoutAttributes:` BUT it's default implementation is empty!. Basically, UICollectionViewCell has other private method called `_setLayoutAttributes:` and this private method is called by UICollectionView and this private method calls `applyLayoutAttributes:` at the end. Default layout attributes, like frame, position, transform are applied with current `animationDuration` before `applyLayoutAttributes:` is called.
That said, you have to override `animationDuration` in private method `_setLayoutAttributes:`

```
- (void) _setLayoutAttributes:(PSTCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
{
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    [super _setLayoutAttributes:layoutAttributes];
}
```

This is obviously, not applestore-safe. You can use one of those runtime hacks to override this private method safely.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the layer's speed property (like in [Rotoava's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23146861/5271393)) to change the control the speed of the animation. The problem is you are using arbitrary values because you do not know the actual duration of the insertion animation.

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225517/what-is-the-default-animation-duration-for-uicollectionview-layout-changes) you can figure out what the default animation duration is.

```
newAnimationDuration = (1/layer.speed)*originalAnimationDuration
layer.speed = originalAnimationDuration/newAnimationDuration
```

If you wanted to make the animation 400ms long, in your layout you would:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [super finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //set attributes here
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGFloat originalAnimationDuration = [CATransaction animationDuration];
    CGFloat newAnimationDuration = 0.4f;
    cell.layer.speed = originalAnimationDuration/newAnimationDuration;
    return attributes;
}
```

In my case I had cells which could be dragged off screen and I wanted to change the duration of the deletion animation based on the speed of the pan gesture.

In the gesture recognizer (which should be part of your collection view):

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint dragVelocityVector = [sender velocityInView:self.collectionView];
    CGFloat dragVelocity = sqrt(dragVelocityVector.x*dragVelocityVector.x + dragVelocityVector.y*dragVelocityVector.y);
    switch (sender.state) {
    ...
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
        CustomLayoutClass *layout = (CustomLayoutClass *)self.collectionViewLayout;
        layout.dragSpeed = fabs(dragVelocity);
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your customLayout:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [super finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGFloat animationDistance = sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
    CGFloat originalAnimationDuration = [CATransaction animationDuration];
    CGFloat newAnimationDuration = animationDistance/self.dragSpeed;
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.speed = originalAnimationDuration/newAnimationDuration;
    return attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without subclassing:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
  [self.collection reloadSections:indexSet];
}];
```

Comment: I'm surprised this is the bottom answer. Worked for me. I did my `performBatchUpdates` within an `UIView` animate closure instead of `reloadSections`

Answer (score 1):

An update to @AshleyMills since forBaselineLayout is deprecated

This works

```
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
    let indexSet = IndexSet(0...(numberOfSections - 1))
    self.collectionView.insertSections(indexSet)
    self.collectionView.forFirstBaselineLayout.layer.speed = 0.5
}, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
    self.collectionView.forFirstBaselineLayout.layer.speed = 1.0
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change UICollectionView layout.speed property, that should change animation duration of your layout...

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom animator using Private API named `-performBatchUpdates:withAnimator:`

(Caution: Apple will reject your app)

```objectivec
__attribute__((objc_direct_members))
@interface UICollectionView (RA_Category)
- (void)ra_performBatchUpdates:(void (^)(void))updates;
@end

@implementation UICollectionView (RA_Category)

- (void)ra_performBatchUpdates:(void (^)())updates {
    UIViewPropertyAnimator *animator = [[UIViewPropertyAnimator alloc] initWithDuration:2.f curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:nil];
    
    reinterpret_cast<void (*)(id, SEL, id, id)>(objc_msgSend)(self,
                                                              sel_registerName("performBatchUpdates:withAnimator:"),
                                                              updates,
                                                              animator);
    
    [animator release];
}

@end
```

or you can override `-[UICollectionViewLayout _propertyAnimatorForCollectionViewUpdates:withCustomAnimator:]`

```objectivec
@implementation CollectionViewLayout

- (id)_propertyAnimatorForCollectionViewUpdates:(id)arg1 withCustomAnimator:(id)arg2 {
    UIViewPropertyAnimator *animator = [[UIViewPropertyAnimator alloc] initWithDuration:1.f curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:nil];
    
    return [animator autorelease];
}

@end
```